# Managing Users through a CRUD Interface -Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

Does Ruby on Rails have a basic user management system or a CRUD similar to http://www.grocerycrud.com I'm looking for a way to manage users like create add update or delete a user.

Comment: I thought that Rails is almost exclusively about CRUD.

Comment: Obviously there are degrees to CRUD and something out there has more of it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Rails uses "restful resources" to implement CRUD, it's a very fundamental subject. I would suggest you do some Rails tutorials.

"[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)" and "[Rails RESTful Resources Tutorial](http://blogs.oracle.com/divas/entry/restful_rails_tutorial)" should get you started.

If you want something specifically for users, take a look at the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem.

Comment: I'm not a Ruby developer doing this for a simple project so I need a plugin or gem or some sort that I can work with it to fit my needs. but it should very basic to create a user delete update and read

Comment: @ReggieJohnson Added a user specific answer.

Comment: I am not sure Devise comes with an interface for Admin's to manage users CRUD style

Comment: Instead of saying "this" and "this", why not use something a bit more descriptive? See "[Don't use "click here" as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)" and "[Link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text)" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all hard to build a CRUD interface with rails(http://railsforzombies.org/ has examples.)

There are plenty of gems that let an admin manage users here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces has more examples